# Changing custom FileInfo constructor parameter from fileName to fileNameOrPath

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to implement some of the behaviors just by referring FileInfo and DirectoryInfo sealed classes.

FileInfo is having only one constructor. It takes either filename or path.

```
FileInfo fileInfoOne = new FileInfo("Sample.txt");
FileInfo fileInfoTwo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Test\Sample.txt");
```

DirectoryInfo is having only one constructor and it takes path.

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test\");
```

FileInfo and DirectoryInfo constructors look like

```
public FileInfo(string fileName);
public DirectoryInfo(string path);
```

Here, DirectoryInfo accepts path as string and that makes sense. But, FileInfo accepts fileName as string and we can pass either name or path, this looks bit odd to me.

I just want to change constructor as below.

```
 public FileInfo(string fileNameOrPath);
```

Am I breaking any design rules (naming conversion point of view)?

Note: I referred FileInfo and DirectoryInfo just for reference. My issue is similar but not exactly same.

**UPDATE:**

Basically we are implementing TextFileInfo, PdfFileInfo, DocFileInfo and etc.,. Each of these file types have their own properties on top of common properties (based on client requirement like "TextLanguage" for DocFileInfo). Common properties wanted to keep in base MasterFileInfo class which is similar to FileInfo.

Any Final suggestions?

Comment: It's not file name or path, it's a fully qualified filename (including the path) or a relative file name. Read the description on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: But I guess what you are actually asking is about constructor parameter naming for your own classes where you can pass in a string, but it could be interpreted as two different things. Is that correct? Perhaps you can include you own code rather than confusing the issue by talking about `FileInfo` which really doesn't do that. It's a filename in both cases.

Comment: The first action of the `FileInfo` constructor is to call [`GetFullPathInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,72f9fabbc9d544a5,references).

Comment: @Matt Burland. Yes I am asking for my own class

Comment: can we see the code which confuses you for your own classes?

Comment: Are you asking if it's ok to name your argument `fileNameOrPath`? If that's what it is, then yes - name your argument however you like as long as they're descriptive and correct.

Comment: Well then like I said, maybe edit the question to ask about your class and not about `FileInfo`. In general, this would be something of a judgement call. In the case of `FileInfo`, the difference between a relative filename and a fully qualified filename is, IMHO, close enough that I think this is fine. If it was as different as a path and a filename, then I'd question the design of your class.

Comment: @doctor I can't provide the code here now. Basically I need to perform lot of file operations and going to re-write most of the things in FileInfo() class adding lot of custom features. My question is while re-writing Can I change constructor a bit just to make more sense? It's just naming conversion point of view. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @rajasekharareddy: why do you need to rew-write most of the things in `FileInfo`? Why can't your class not simply hold one or multiple `FileInfo` objects?

Comment: @rajasekharareddy, yes you can do anything you like. but if someone use [named arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) to call the constructor and you change it later then that will make trouble.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Basically we are implementing TextFileInfo, PdfFileInfo, DocFileInfo and etc.,. Each of these file types have their own properties on top of common properties (based on client requirement like "TextLanguage" for DocFileInfo). Common properties wanted to keep in base MasterFileInfo class which is similar to FileInfo. As others said I am going to keep "fileNameOrPath" in MasterFileInfo constructor and initializing FileInfo constructor.

Comment: Ok, but if all you are doing is passing your `fileNameOrPath` to `FileInfo`, then your argument name is now *more* not less confusing. Because as I said before, you *always* pass a filename to `FileInfo` and you *never* pass a path. A fully qualified filename (that includes the path) isn't the same as a path by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path and file name are operating system concepts, when you say `my.txt` it means a file with name `my.txt` in current folder and the file handle will be pointing to something like `D:\data\temp\my.txt` where `D:\data\temp\` is the current folder. You can also give `..\..\my.txt` as path to the constructor and it means that go 2 directory up form current directory and look for a file named `my.txt` and it will be converted to `D:\my.txt` if current directory is `D:\data\temp\`.

Also notice that both

```
FileInfo fileInfoOne = new FileInfo("Sample.txt");
FileInfo fileInfoTwo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Test\Sample.txt");
```

will call the [same constructor for FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Not sure that answers the question. But I'm not exactly sure what the question actually is.

Answer (score 0):

While I would disagree with your stating the `FileInfo` constructor parameter name/description doesn't make sense, based on the comments it sounds like you could do something like this:

```
public class FileInfoPassthrough // Could this be considered a facade?
{

    /// <summary>
    /// A much more descriptive parameter name for the FileInfo constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileNameOrPath">Either the filename at the relative path of execution, or the full filename and path.</param>
    public FileInfo GetFileInfo(string fileNameOrPath)
    {
         return new FileInfo(fileNameOrPath);
    }
}
```

this would allow you to have a "more descriptive" parameter name, which simply news up a `FileInfo` and returns it.  You could use this method in place of newing up a `FileInfo` in various places.

The newing up of the `FileInfo` object via this class abstracts away the "bad name/description" of the constructor in `FileInfo` from the consumer (assuming they use this method and not the `FileInfo` directly).